# Using static value in a distinct clause

Tags: sql, distinct

Since i'm new to SQL i'm not able to understand what is the difference between following statements:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x , 66 FROM Person
```

**vs**

```
SELECT s.x, 66 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT x FROM Person ) s
```

Is there any Performance Difference.
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no logical difference because the constant `66` does not influence whether two rows are equal or not.

I suspect there is no performance difference either because probably the optimizer can pick up this pattern and transform the first to the second form. Look at the execution plan in your favorite RDBMS to find out.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any (significant/detectable) difference because the query optimizer can see it is same.

You can see this yourself by looking at the execution plan for the queries and/or the IO and TIME statistics for the query.
In my own tests, they all were the same.
Both result in a scan and a scalar computation.

If I were to choose I'd go with #1 because it's easier to read and because it avoids the sub select

A difference can come if you start putting more logic into the query and especially the sub query. So always test changes.

Answer (score 0):

This even does the same again, do you see the pattern? You are just creating another query, one level deeper, to pre-generate your result set. You can do that as often as you like, and *if* you are lucky, the optimizer is going to see through it for a while.

```
SELECT s.x, 66 FROM (SELECT t.x as x FROM ( SELECT DINSTINCT x FROM Person ) t ) s
```

In the end, always try to go with the best readable and best maintainable solution, not introducing subqueries where they are not needed. In most cases it is trivial to introduce superfluous subqueries to achieve teh same result, but other than willingly annoy any developers that come after you, I would not see why you would want to do it :)